# REST SECURE SECRET KEY

Tags: java, json, rest, security, secret-key

I am writing a JAVA REST webservice, I'm trying to understand how it all works, but I've managed to make simple methods where my client will send a JSON with information, and the server does something with it. Very easy.

So what I am doing: My client wants to create a new object, for example, an account, yet I don't want everyone on the world to simply send a json to my website and create an object.
However I don't want to filter on IP's, because I got no clue who or what will use my client application.

So what have I done to prevent everyone to simply send data? I've created a secret key for the players and they use it like: 
http://[website]/[Applicationname]/Webresources/[SECRETKEY]/create
(Send a json with the request)

This works, since now only people with the secretkey can create, and they will only get a secret key if I give it to them. I am pretty sure they won't be giving this secret key to others, since if they do so, they only screw themselves, their services will get loads of fake data...
Yet I want it to be more secure, so noone can obtain the key no matter what, and I don't know if HTTPS will also hide the domain + parameters, I think not, right?

So my question is: **how can I send a secret key, without anyone EVER finding out what the secret key is?**

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel poorly. Lookup how to do OAUTH2

Comment: I'm not reïnventing anything :P I did it this way because I did not know any other way, but thanks, I'll look into the OAUTH2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HTTPS, send POST requests for which you specify your secret key data in the body. You should specify the Content Type to be "x-www-form-urlencoded". The content should be encoded, and adversaries who intercept the url will not be able to decipher the body.

However, your implementation is pretty insecure for sending each request by using the secret key in the URL path, as any adversary intercepting the REST call will know the secret key just by looking at the url. It's way harder and longer to implement but if you can do a Basic Auth or OAuth authorization service, it will authorize only specific users with valid tokens issued to them to access the service, which is the general way of securing your REST services.

Comment: Indeed, standards like OAuth, Basic, Digest are the simplest and secure way to go. Next to that - every WS / REST framework (CXF, Spring, Axis, ..) has a way to implement an authentication / authorization option, try to use already implemented options